# Angular component works perfectly locally, but gives me an error when deployed to Azure

Tags: angular, typescript, azure

I'm working on an app involving seasons and calendars.

I can get it working it locally, but when I deploy it to an Azure Web app, I get an error message, even though the data and the code is exactly the same.

```
ERROR RangeError: Invalid array length
    at w.getDays (11.5e980b78c274ae5687fd.chunk.js:1)
    at new w (11.5e980b78c274ae5687fd.chunk.js:1)
    at ns (main.af3705283ae2dd27e166.bundle.js:1)
    at Jr (main.af3705283ae2dd27e166.bundle.js:1)
    at As (main.af3705283ae2dd27e166.bundle.js:1)
    at Is (main.af3705283ae2dd27e166.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.Ws [as createRootView] (main.af3705283ae2dd27e166.bundle.js:1)
    at Sr.create (main.af3705283ae2dd27e166.bundle.js:1)
    at ae.create (main.af3705283ae2dd27e166.bundle.js:1)
    at t._getContentRef (main.af3705283ae2dd27e166.bundle.js:1)
```

The error message appears when I try to open a bootstrap modal by clicking on a button, which loads the modal component by passing in the data from the list row.

I know that the error is not in the data being passed in as I'm using exactly the same data locally, and on Azure. Could it be some kind of azure incompatibility issue?

Here is the code that that opens ths component:

```
onAddClick() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.show(EditSeasonComponent, {
      initialState: {
        calendarId: this.selectedCalendarId,
      }
    });
    this.modalCloseSubscription = (<EditSeasonComponent>modalRef.content).onModalClose
      .subscribe(season => {
        if (season) {
          this.seasons.push(season);
          this.seasonsUpdated.emit(this.sortSeasons());
          this.modalCloseSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
      });
  }

  onEditClick(season: Season) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.show(EditSeasonComponent, {
      initialState: {
        season,
        calendarId: this.selectedCalendarId,
        modalTitle: 'Edit Season'
      }
    });
    this.modalCloseSubscription = (<EditSeasonComponent>modalRef.content).onModalClose
      .subscribe(savedSeason => {
        if (savedSeason) {
          this.seasons.splice(this.seasons.findIndex(s => s.id === savedSeason.id), 1, savedSeason);
          this.seasonsUpdated.emit(this.sortSeasons());
          this.modalCloseSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
      });
  }
```

Here is the code for the modal component:

```
export class EditSeasonComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('editSeason', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  public containerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  seasonForm: FormGroup;
  season: Season = new Season();
  calendarId: number;
  modalTitle = 'Add Season';
  onModalClose = new EventEmitter<Season>();
  months: MonthItem[];
  days: number[] = this.getDays(0);
  constructor(
    private bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dialogService: DialogService,
    private calendarService: CalendarService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    if (this.season.id) {
      this.setValues();
    }
    this.months = moment.months().map((m, i) => {
      return { value: i, text: m };
    });
  }

  createForm() {
    this.seasonForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      month: 0,
      day: 1
    });
    this.seasonForm.get('month').valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.days = this.getDays(value);
        if (this.seasonForm.get('day').value > this.days.length) {
          this.seasonForm.patchValue({ day: this.days.length });
        }
      });
  }

  getDays(month: number) {
    const daysInmonth = moment().month(month).daysInMonth();
    return Array.from(new Array(daysInmonth), (val, index) => {
        return index + 1;
    });
  }

  get name() { return this.seasonForm.get('name'); }

  setValues() {
    this.seasonForm.reset(this.season);
  }

  onCloseClick(dialogResult$: Observable<DialogAction | DialogCloseResult>) {
    if (dialogResult$) {
      dialogResult$.subscribe((result: DialogAction | DialogCloseResult) => {
        if (result instanceof DialogCloseResult) {

        } else if (result.primary) {
          this.onSubmit();
        } else {
          this.onModalClose.emit(null);
          this.bsModalRef.hide();
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.bsModalRef.hide();
      this.onModalClose.emit(null);
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.seasonForm.invalid) {
      touchControls(this.seasonForm);
      return;
    }
    if (this.season.id) {
      this.calendarService.updateSeason(this.calendarId, this.season.id, this.prepareSubmit())
        .subscribe(season => {
          this.notificationService.addMessage(NotificationType.Info, 'Season Updated Successfully');
          this.onAddUpdateSeason(season);
        }
        );
    } else {
      this.calendarService.addSeason(this.calendarId, this.prepareSubmit())
        .subscribe( season => {
          this.notificationService.addMessage(NotificationType.Info, 'Season Added Successfully');
          this.onAddUpdateSeason(season);
        }
        );
    }
  }

  onAddUpdateSeason(season: Season) {
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
    this.onModalClose.emit(season);
  }

  prepareSubmit(): SaveSeason {
    const formModel = this.seasonForm.value;
    const saveSeason: SaveSeason = Object.assign(new SaveSeason(this.season), formModel);
    saveSeason.calendarId = this.calendarId;
    return saveSeason;
  }

  showDialog(): Observable<DialogAction | DialogCloseResult> {
    const dialogRef: DialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
      appendTo: this.containerRef,
      title: 'Unsaved Changes',
      content: 'The season has unsaved changes. Would you like to save the changes?',
      actions: [
        { text: 'No' },
        { text: 'Yes', primary: true }
      ]
    });
    return dialogRef.result;
  }
}

interface MonthItem {
  value: number;
  text: string;
}
```

And this is the template:

```
<app-generic-modal [group]="seasonForm"
                   [title]="modalTitle"
                   [saveTooltip]="'Save Season'"
                   [dirtyDialogName]="'season'"
                   (closeClick)="onCloseClick($event)"
                   (submitForm)="onSubmit()">
  <ng-template appGenericModalContent let-group>
    <div class="form-row form-group">
      <div class="col">
        <label for="edit-season-name">Name<span class="k-required text-danger">*</span></label>
        <input id="edit-season-name"
                class="form-control form-control-sm"
                type="text"
               [formControl]="group.get('name')"
                maxlength="64"/>
        <div class="error-container text-danger" *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)">
          <div *ngIf="name.errors.required" class="font-weight-normal">
            Name is required
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row form-group">
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="edit-season-month">Month</label>
        <kendo-dropdownlist [formControl]="group.get('month')"
                            id="edit-season-day"
                            [data]="months"
                            textField="text"
                            valueField="value"
                            [valuePrimitive]="true"></kendo-dropdownlist>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="edit-season-day">Day</label>
        <kendo-dropdownlist [formControl]="group.get('day')"
                            id="edit-season-day"
                            [data]="days"></kendo-dropdownlist>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</app-generic-modal>
```

Please advise me with how to proceed with this, I've been pulling my hair out for a few days trying to find the issue.

Comment: my guess is that the app not being properly loaded. Take a look on the network tab and check if all the files are properly loaded (200 status code). Also, chunk.js and bundle.js leads me to think you're minifying your js code. When facing a JS problem, I recommend you "debug" with no minified version so you can better track and change the code on the fly (if using chrome for example)

Comment: The app is working just fine on debug (locally), I get the problem when its deployed to an Azure Web app (production). There are no network errors too. Do you think updating all the packages could fix this ?

Comment: no, seems that you're setting negative values for some of your arrays

Comment: Hi, after some investigating, I found that const daysInmonth = moment().month(0).daysInMonth(); is returning a NaN, I'm looking at why that's happening now.

Comment: In one case you're using moment().month(), in another moment.month(). I don't see in your code where moment is defined, but I don't think you should be using it as both a function and an object - and it would explain the NaN error, though not necessarily explain why it's working locally (unless you're using different build modes)

Comment: So, I got it resolved by removing moment altogether. For months, I'm using a hard coded array, and for days in a month, I'm using JavaScript Date object. The errors were resolved after that.